# gstreamer android client to stream udp multicast smooth on android 4.1 but choppy in 4.0.4

Tags: udp, gstreamer, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, multicast

I'm working with tutorial3 from **slomo gst-sdk-tutorials** for gstreamer1.0,

I can play a streaming video smoothly in android 4.1 but in 4.0 the quality is not smooth enough , the following are the information retrieved by `ffmpeg -i` :

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://224.2.2.2:1234':
  Duration: N/A, start: 2024.535278, bitrate: 128 kb/s
  Program 259 
    Stream #0:0[0x109]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x10a]: Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
```

My pipeline is :

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=1234 multicast-group=224.2.2.2  ! tsdemux !  mpegvideoparse ! mpeg2dec ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=25/1 ! autovideosink sync=false
```

Can anyone help me to find the right pipeline to play video smoothly + audio ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to receive better answers.

Comment: Just in case another person meet this behaviour, it was just a manufacturer issue. Now i play UDP streams directly via Android SurfaceView, and it works in most SetTopBox.